# Probability proof using Bonferroni inequality & union bound

Tags: probability

let $\mathcal{A}=\left\{ A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{n}\right\}$ a finite set of events in $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1}\cap A_{2}\right)=0$ for all $A_{1},A_{2}\in\mathcal{A}$ and $ \mathbb{P}\left(\underset{A\in\mathcal{A}}{\bigcup}A\right)=1$. Show that every event $B$ apply: $\underset{A\in\mathcal{A}}{\sum}\mathbb{P}\left(B\cap A\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(B\right)$.

---

I'm trying to prove that $\underset{A\in\mathcal{A}}{\sum}\mathbb{P}\left(B\cap A\right)\geqslant\mathbb{P}\left(B\right)$ using bonferroni's second inequality and $\underset{A\in\mathcal{A}}{\sum}\mathbb{P}\left(B\cap A\right)\leqslant\mathbb{P}\left(B\right)$ using the union bound, but I find myself lost in set-theorem (which I haven't learnt) nuances of unions and intersections

Answer (score 1):

Here are the main steps and I will you do the verifications:

Let $C=(\Omega \setminus \bigcup_i A_i) \bigcup ( \bigcup_{i \neq j} A_i \cap A_j)$.  Then

$P(C)=0$

$C_i \equiv A_i\setminus C$, $1\leq i \leq n$, are disjoint.

$P(B)=P(B\setminus C) \leq P(\bigcup (B \cap  A_i))\leq \sum P(B\cap A_i)$

and

$\sum P(B\cap A_i) =\sum P(B \cap C_i)= P(B \bigcup C_i) \leq P(B)$